# HTML, CSS - Issue changing view web page

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I used flex for defining the inline content however when I use the media query property I see that once I pass to the smartphone view the header/menu bar gets behind the section (#media).

How do I solve the problem? I tried changing the display property but still the problem persist and other properties but nothing work the second contend hide the menu bar.

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Emblem</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bellefair|Lato|Source+Sans+Pro|Zilla+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../common_css/common_style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <section id="top-header">
            <section id="logo">
                <figure>
                    <img src="../common_img/logo.png" alt="Emblem Rare, Collectible Books">
                </figure>
                <h1>Emblem</h1>
            </section>
            <h1 class="title">HOME</h1>
            <section id="accessibility">
                <ul id="link">
                    <li><a href="#">Contact&nbsp;Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Accessibility</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </section>

        <nav>
            <ul id="nav-bar">
                <li class="active"><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Books</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#">18Th Century Books</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">19Th Century Books</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">20Th Century Books</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Book as an Investment</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

    </header>

    <section id="media">
<video controls >
                <source src="video/emblem_video_480x360.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                <source src="video/emblem_video_480x360.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                Sorry, It seem that your browser does not support HTML5 video tag. Please try with Chrome 5 or above.
            </video>

            <section id="media-images">
                <figure>
                    <img src="img/rumpour_at_nightfall.jpeg" alt="Rumpour At Nightfall">
                    <img src="img/ulysses.jpeg" alt="Ulysses">
                    <figcaption>At the left Rumpour At Nightfall and at the right Ulysses</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </section>


    <p>PRova</p>
    </section>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code

```
/*reset to default all the browser settings*/
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: inherit;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: "DefaultFont";
    src: url("../fonts/parisr.ttf");
}


li{
    list-style: none;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}




#top-header{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
    /*Logo*/
    #logo{
        margin-left: 2rem;
    }
        #logo img{
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }

        #logo h1{
            text-align: center;
            font-family: DefaultFont;
            font-size: 2rem;
            font-weight: 800;
            color: #236841;
        }
    .title{
        padding: 0 2rem;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-size: 2rem;
        color: #236841;
        border-left: 3px solid #236841;
        border-right: 3px solid #236841;
    }
    #accessibility{
        margin-right: 2rem;
    }

        #link{
            display: flex;
        }

        #accessibility ul li{
            min-width: 4rem;
            padding-left: 7%;
        }

        #accessibility ul li a{
            font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;
            font-weight: 600;
            color: #236841;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
        }

        #accessibility ul li a:hover{
            color: #40bf77;
        }



#nav-bar{
    height: 4rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
    #nav-bar li{
        width: 20%;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #236841;
        line-height: 4rem;
        border-left: 1px solid white;
    }

    #nav-bar li:first-child{
        border-left: none;
    }
    #nav-bar li:hover{
        background-color: #239B56;
    }

    #nav-bar a{
        min-width: 8rem;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Bellefair', serif;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 1rem;
        color: white;
    }

    #nav-bar li .dropdown{
        display: none;
    }


    #nav-bar li:hover .dropdown{
        position: absolute;
        display: flex;
        margin-left: -15%;
        width: 50%;
        justify-content: center;

    }




@media screen and (max-width: 1002px) {

    #top-header{
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }
    #logo{
            margin: 0;
            width: 180px;
            height: auto;
    }
    .title{
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }

    #nav-bar li {
        width: 100%;
        border-left: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    }

    #nav-bar {  
        display: block;
    }
    #nav-bar li:hover .dropdown{
        margin-left: 0%;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
    header{
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
        height: 30%;
    }
    #top-header{
        display: block;
    }
    #logo{
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
    }
    #logo figure img {
        width: 150px;
    }
    #link{
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .title{
        text-align: center;
        padding: 2 0rem;
        color: #236841;
        border-top: 3px solid #236841;
        border-bottom: 3px solid #236841;
        border-left: 0;
        border-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Why am I having this problem? I always used flex and always worked fine. If anyone know the reason could you please explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are setting the height of the header nav in your css:

```
#nav-bar {
    height: 4rem;
```

Comment: sn3ll Thank you very much, I did not notice that while I was revising, about the is everything ok? or too much similar code? If you can could you please share your opinion about the css code?

Answer (score 0):

Take the explicit height off the `#nav-bar` and add

```
nav {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Which will clear the elements after it. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/xqrk2nv6/